# Setting up the VirtualHost Configuration File-web page not loading

Tags: server, apache2

I have been following official documentation,to set up apache server https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#4-setting-up-the-virtualhost-configuration-file. But the not able to load webpage.
Here I am attesting what I did.

[Terminal image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg71Q.png)

[Terminal image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5DPp.png)

[browser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXoaS.png)

Kindly tell me where did I go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `example.com` address you’re pointing to is a real domain owned by someone else, and your computer doesn’t know to look internally for that DNS record rather than externally.

The simplest way to solve this would be to add a line in your `/etc/hosts` file that looks something like:

```
127.0.0.1     gci.example.com
```

This will tell your machine to use `127.0.0.1`, your computer, whenever anything asks for `gci.example.com`. Generally it’s better to use a domain that doesn’t exist when doing development, such as `.ubuntu` or `.mypc`. This reduces the chance of an application such as Chrome or FireFox from using an external DNS lookup and sending you somewhere else.